# A dictionary with in dictionary that only gets created when the current dataset requires it

Tags: python

I have a dictionary inside a dictionary:

```
dict['specialdata']={}
```

Now it gets filled, but I want that dictionary only appear in return or print statements when it contains actual data.

So when I return it for a dataset that has no special data, I don't want there to be an empty dictionary. Just no inner dictionary at all.

Comment: dictionary get filled?

Comment: ...don't add the inner dictionary until you've something to put in it?

Comment: why add a dictionary if you have nothing to put in it?

Comment: Please don't name your own dictionary `dict`, you are overwriting the name of a built-in class. Name it `mydict` or whatever you want, anything but `dict` ...

Comment: Ok, i got that, what i meant was i have maybe 10 sets of data that gets put into the main dict , and some of them have data that goes into the inside dict, and some of them don't. On those occasions i don't wanna be shown an empty dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to check if your dictionary is empty or not then print it out.
So this will do what you want

```
if dict['key']:
    print dict['key']
else:
    #Other stuff
    None
```

`if dict['key']` conditions checks if your dictionary contain any keys or not.

Comment: The pythonic way to write that would be `if mydict['key']: print mydict['key']`, no need for inline if-statements.